# Specify cert to use for SSL in docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, ssl, curl, docker-compose

I've got a small `docker-compose.yaml` file that looks like this (it's used to fire up a local test-environment):

```
version: '2'

services:
    ubuntu:
        build:
            context: ./build
            dockerfile: ubuntu.dock
        volumes:
            - ./transfer:/home/
        ports:
            - "60000:22"
    python:
        build:
            context: ./build
            dockerfile: python.dock
        volumes:
            - .:/home/code
        links:
            - mssql
            - ubuntu
    mssql:
      image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
      environment:
          SA_PASSWORD: "somepassword"
          ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      ports:
          - "1433:1433"
```

The issue that I run into is that when I run `docker-compose up` it fails at this step (which is in the `python.dock` file):

```
Step 10/19 : RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
 ---> Running in e4963c91a05b
```

The error looks like this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

The part where it fails in the `python.dock` file looks like this:

```
# This line fails
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
```

I've had issues with curl / docker in the past - because we use a self-signed cert for decrypting/encrypting at the firewall level (network requirement); is there a way for me to specify a self-signed cert for the containers to use?

That would allow curl to reach out and download the required files.

I've tried running something like `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml --tlscert ~/certs/the-self-signed-ca.pem up` but it fails.

How can I do this a bit more programatically so I can just run `docker-compose up` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, your firewall breaks the TLS encryption and re-encrypts it with a certificate from a local CA. I think this is generally a bad situation and you should aim for proper end-to-end, but politics aside.

The argument `--tlscert` passed to `docker-compose` is used to communicate with the docker daemon, potentially running remotely, exposed on port 2376, by default. In such a scenario, your local `docker-compose` command orchestrates containers on a remote machine, including building the image.

In your case, the `curl` command runs within a container. It will use the CAs (usually) installed by the base image in `python.dock`. To use your custom CA, you need to either

- copy the CA certificate to the correct place within the image, e.g.,

  ```
  COPY the-self-signed-ca.pem /etc/ssl/certs/
  ```

  The exact procedure depends on your base image. This will make the certificate available in the container. The certificate will most likely be used by all subsequent processes. Other developers/users might not be aware that a custom CA is installed and that the connection is not secure!
- copy the CA certificate to a custom place within the image, e.g.,

  ```
  COPY the-self-signed-ca.pem /some/path/the-self-signed-ca.pem
  ```

  and tell curl explicitly about the custom CA using the `--cacert` argument:

  ```
  RUN curl --cacert /some/path/the-self-signed-ca.pem https://example.com/
  ```

Comment: I don't disagree about breaking the TLS - but in certain organizations, for certain reasons, it's a 'necessary evil' and in this case it does more good than the harm of requiring a few additional workarounds. Your answer does the trick! Thanks a bunch!